# Spring mail using Gmail SMTP server

Tags: spring, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have implemented simple email sending client as show in http://www.baeldung.com/spring-email. I used Gmail smtp server, everything works fine but google sets "from" field to email of which I have connected to smtp server. This is a problem because I want that "from" field would be an email address which client entered. Does anyone know how to solve it??

P.S. I have found this https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en but it is not an option.

Comment: I understand that you need custom alias for "from" field?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail is not going to let you send messages that appear to come from any arbitrary email address because that would allow you to spam or phish people with a forged From address.